# Web API: EF6 issue with multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm getting the following error in my web API application.

"An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

**Step 1:** Browser posts an edited Release to API controller, which in turn calls update on a Service.

**ReleaseController.cs**

```
public Guid Update(EditReleaseViewModel release)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) throw new Exception("Invalid model");

        var updatedRelease = _releaseService.Update(release);
        return updatedRelease.ID;
    }
```

**Step 2:** Service retrieves and modifies the Release. (The service gets the DbContext injected per request with Ninject)

**ReleaseService.cs**

```
public Release Update(EditReleaseViewModel release)
    {
        var existingRelease = _context.Releases.Single(x => x.ID == release.ID);

        existingRelease.Name = release.Name;
        existingRelease.CatalogNumber = release.CatalogNumber;

        _context.Entry(existingRelease).State = EntityState.Modified; // ERROR HAPPENS HERE!
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return existingRelease;
    }
```

I read that this happens when an entity is still in memory (wasn't detached before disposing previous DbContext).

Could the problem be that I'm using the same Service to retrieve the Release before trying to update it again in that same service?

And if yes, what's the best way around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve existingRelease from the dbcontext one of the benefits is your context is already attached and your state tracking is provided for free.  All you need to do is update your name/catalognumber and call SaveChanges.

```
public Release Update(EditReleaseViewModel release)
{
    var existingRelease = _context.Releases.Single(x => x.ID == release.ID);

    existingRelease.Name = release.Name;
    existingRelease.CatalogNumber = release.CatalogNumber;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return existingRelease;
}
```

When you manually set the state of the entity like so:

```
_context.Entry(existingRelease).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Two things happen here: 1) it tries to attach existingRelease to _context (which fails here because it's already attached to it from the retrieval) and 2) marks ALL properties as modified -- rather than only the 2 you've updated.

Hope that helps.